# [Python2.7] or [Python-2.7]?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, retag-request

For some reason we have both a [python2.7](/questions/tagged/python2.7) and a [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7). I don't have enough votes in either tag to suggest a synonym and the 15 posts in [Python2.7] is just outside my limits of gruntwork to retag them all.

Can somebody merge them?

Comment: A lot of those should just have the version-qualified tag removed, actually.

Comment: @Nicholas: That's even *more* work than just retagging with [python-2.7]!

Comment: I suggest inventing an AI to do it for you.

Comment: @Nicholas: I have one, but it only supports Python 2.5 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Retag  has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). However, I can't suggest the synonym, so we'll have to wait on that.